# math syllabus US education system 1-12th Grade

Tags: secondary-education, primary-education, usa, syllabus

Please share links to websites / pdf files containing syllabus in subject mathematics in US education system Grades 1-12.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like the common core standards? The main website for that seems to be down. Here's the CA info: https://www.cde.ca.gov/re/cc/mathresources.asp

Comment: Thank you for the link, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: The link works if you click on it.

Comment: I know that one has to click on links haha.. but I am in a different geographical location.. so here it does not work. I am in Europe.

Comment: The link provided by Sue in a comment works for me.  (I'm in the Philippines, South East Asia.)

Comment: This is not an answer, but the fact is that there is no national/federal U.S. curriculum. The U.S. is made up of 50 states, each with its own State Board of Education. In the U.S. there are about 14,000 public school districts and more than 130,000 public schools. Sometimes there isn't even a standard curriculum for the same subject taught by two different teachers in the same school, much less within a school district or a state or the whole country. And then there are public charter schools, private independent schools, private parochial schools, homeschooling (each state has its own laws).

Answer (score -1):

Texas has its own curriculum so it does not follow the Common Core Standards.

https://tea.texas.gov/academics/curriculum-standards/teks-review/mathematics-texas-essential-knowledge-and-skills